# QTP doesn't generate a code when a window application opens for testing

Tags: qtp

I am new to QTP.
Just started recording my first test.
I opened the calcuator windows application.QTP should create a code right??? but it doesn't happen as a result I cannot run my test. thats the code

```
Window("Calculator").WinButton("5").Click
Window("Calculator").WinButton("*").Click
Window("Calculator").WinButton("*").Click
Window("Calculator").WinButton("9").Click
Window("Calculator").WinButton("=").Click
Window("Calculator").Close
```

thats the error

> Cannot find the "5" object's parent "Calculator" (class Window). Verify that parent properties match an object currently displayed in your application.
>
> Line (1): "Window("Calculator").WinButton("5").Click".

Answer (score 3):

It's saying it can't find the calculator test object. Make sure that Calculator is open (and that there is only one instance). If you want QTP to launch calculator you can enter `calc.exe` in the **Record & Run Settings**.

QTP by default ignores all windows applications (except those it knows people often test e.g. firefox) you must either add the name of the application you want to test in the **R&R settings** or check the *record and run on any windows application* checkbox.

Comment: thank u for helping but what does it mean "there is only one instance"Why my QTP doesn't run as in youtube tutorials for QTP

Comment: @jyoti, is there a calculator window open when you run the test?

Comment: Do I have to add every window application in record &run setting before making a test. e.g. even QTP wasn't identifying the notepad. Its wierd

Comment: @jyoti, you must either specify which application you're testing or check the **record and run on all windows applications** checkbox

Comment: @jyoti, you should accept the answer if this solved your problem

Comment: I wonder how a user can have such a hard time understanding the dox, and this answer, for a software that is as cost-intensive as QTP. Who provides such people with such software, I wonder?!? Sigh. It´s like a bicyclist trying to land a Jumbo with zero flight experience.